# Did Eichiro Oda the first mangaka that make a side-story of certain character in his cover chapter?

Tags: one-piece, mangaka

I would like to know if there are other mangakas like Eiichiro Oda who make an illustration cover of a specific chapter to be like a side-story, and it's really like a **canon story**, even it just a side story, for example, this one:

1. [CP9 Side story](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/CP9%27s_Independent_Report)
2. [Buggy's After battle](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Buggy%27s_Crew:_After_the_Battle!)

Is this really common in manga industry? If yes, is there another mangaka that is making this kind of "unusual" side-story? And is Eiichiro Oda the one who started this kind of thing?

Comment: Many big mangaka do this, not only Oda. Masashi Kishimoto of Naruto and Tite Kubo of Bleach have done this.

Comment: @EroSɘnnin did he (oda sensei) the first mangaka who started this trend ?  ?

Comment: Well, it's a common trend for sure. But I would disagree with the your quote saying Oda was the first mangaka. If you're looking at the list of famous manga, then Akira Toriyama, who created Dragon Ball, would be considered as the figure everyone (including Oda) looks up to.

Comment: So no, it wasn't Oda who started the trend. One Piece or Dragon Ball weren't the first manga, but rather the ones that got international recognition. There were plenty of manga and creators before Oda even started.